# Remove 'Server' header in IIS 10

Tags: iis, headers

Our compliance department wants us to remove the 'Server' header when someone hits our server via IP address. I don't know how to accomplish that, can someone help? To be clear, I know how to do this on a website we are hosting  (e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) I can configure IIS to return the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: https://www.example.com/
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2023 22:09:08 GMT
```

But if my site `www.example.com` is at IP address `1.2.3.4` then when I call `http://1.2.3.4` I currently get the following headers back.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 315
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2023 22:11:43 GMT
Connection: close
```

The problem I'm likely having is because 1.2.3.4 is not bound to any site IIS is defaulting to something else. Any ideas?

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be contains all you might need.